# Dependency resolution problem in apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Using `Ubuntu 16.04`

Listing available `apache2` versions:

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# apt-cache show apache2 | grep Version
Version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9
Version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8
Version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3
```

It just so happens I want a specific version (`2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8`) so I am trying to install it as per the following command (which in turn fails as follows):

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# sudo apt-get install apache2=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
           Recommends: ssl-cert but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why doesn't `apt-get` perform the appropriate dependency resolution and install the appropriate needed packages?

What confuses me most is this statement:

```
Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8) but 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installe
```

Why is it trying to install a `3.9` dependency while it is obvious a `3.8` is needed?

Comment: apt always tries to install the highest version. You obviously need to specify the versions of these dependencies as well. I suppose you could file a bug report on this, but it is unlikely to be resolved for older packages. If you install the older version of apache you will need to put those packages on hold as well.

Comment: Something else on your system requires 3.9. Apache requires 3.8. You cannot do both (that's the "impossible situation"), so you must make an executive decision and uninstall one of them.